# Kafka Streams add name to a block of steps in topology

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am creating a kafka streams  library. I am trying to make the topology generic by having a fixed base topology and let the client modify on top of it.

Here is what it looks like:

```
@Override
public void configureTopology(final Topology topology) {
    KafkaStreamsInfrastructureCustomizer.super.configureTopology(topology);
    modifyTopology(topology);
}


@Override
public void configureBuilder(final StreamsBuilder builder) {


    final Consumed<A, B> consumed = config.getConsumed();
    final KStream<A, B> source = builder.stream(config.getSourceTopic(), consumed);
    final KStream<C, D> preProcessedStream = preProcess(builder, source);

    // Skipping the other topology steps which contain transformers. 
    preProcessedStream.process(processorSupplier,
            Named.as("terminal-processor"));
}

public void modifyTopology(final Topology topology) {}


protected abstract KStream<C, D> preProcess(StreamsBuilder builder, KStream<A, B> stream);
```

- The preProcessStream is a function which the client will implement if they want to perform some preprocessing.
- They will use the modifyTopology to add new processors to the existing topology.

##### Questions:

- How can I add a name to the preProcess step so that if someone wants to add a processor in modifyTopology to consume after preProcess step, they can do so like below:

```
public void modifyTopology(final Topology topology) {
  topology.addProcessor("processor-name", OtherProcessor::new, "name-of-preprocess-step");
}
```

> I am aware I can do so by adding a always true filter step with name. But is there any other way?

- Is it fine to use both configureBuilder and configureTopology like this?
  I want to use configureBuilder because I am using a Transformer in my fixed topology.

> I am aware that I can use a processor with context.forward in place of transformer but I want to make the library easy to implement for clients.

Comment: This is basically already provided by https://www.azkarrastreams.io/

Comment: I don't think it will be possible for me to use the library. Could you please suggest what can I do with the above code? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not really sure. Have you considered using SteamBuilder instead of passing around a Topology? Then you can finalize the Topology by building the builder... If you want to add a name to anything, just add a string parameter to the method... That's not a problem unique to Streams API, just generic Java parameters